# Submit button does not submit form data in bootstrap

Tags: submit

I am trying to submit a form in a bootstrap framework and cannot get past the validation, even with correct data.

I think there might be an error with this syntax,

```
    <form name=form1 method=post action=signupck.php onsubmit='return validate(this)'><input type=hidden name=todo value=post>
```

then the form fields... which all display correctly - so no problems there - in the style:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
            <label for="fname">Forename</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Forename"><br></br>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-2">
            <label for="sname">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sname" placeholder="Surname">
            </div>
        </div>
```

and then,

```
     <input type=submit value=Signup>
     <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
```

The form on submission displays signupck.php, signalling validation messages when is should be submitted ok. I have got this working outside the bootstrap, but when I put this inside the template, in the form above, I get the problems.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You are aware there is no " around your type=submit right! Also your inputs aren't self closing... if you don't /> at the end then you aren't closing them off so the browser doesn't know where the input actually ends..

Comment: I'm afraid these didn't work!